# How to access data in a NSDictionary with objectForKey

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary, nsnumber

I'm trying to access the data in a dictionary. I'm able to access the data when it's a string like:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[item objectForKey:@"merchant"]objectForKey:@"name"];
```

but am not sure about the syntax for an NSNumber:

```
NSNumber* latFromTable = [[displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                           [objectForKey:@"coords"]objectForKey:@"lat"];
```

I know I'm using NSStrings in the code above which won't work. How would I change that to work with NSNumber?

the data in the dictionary is presented as the following. The objectForKey is "coords". I want access to item 1 and 2 (lat and lng)

```
 "coords": {
        "lat": 52.5032,
        "lng": 13.3445
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with the code you have now. You're using NSStrings for the keys because the keys are NSStrings; you're returning an NSNumber. Are you getting an error message or a strange result?

Comment: Usually NSNumber works fine with NSDictionarys. Your code should work from what I can see so far. However, in general it may be advisable to fetch objects of type id first and then test whether they are nil or of class NSDictionary or of class NSNumber.

Comment: NSNumber* latFromTable = [[displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                           objectForKey:@"coords"];
this gives me the result as a pair of lat and long.

Comment: What you got obviously is not an NSNumber, bur rather an NSDictionary (containing two NSNumbers).

Comment: yes, that's right! I accessed each one individually with:     NSString *latStr = [latlon objectForKey:@"lat"];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Issue with the following code is mismatching of brackets:

```
NSNumber* latFromTable = [[displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                           [objectForKey:@"coords"]objectForKey:@"lat"];
```

So change it like:

```
float latFromTable = (float)[[[displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                           objectForKey:@"coords"]objectForKey:@"lat"];
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:latFromTable];
```

Comment: thanks! I tried that and I get "undeclared identifier objectAtKey" error. for both.

Comment: Please NSLog (@"%@",[[displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                           [objectForKey:@"coords"]]); What is the output ?

Comment: I found that if I use:  NSNumber* latlonFromTable = [[displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                           objectForKey:@"coords"];
I get lat lon{
    lat = "52.5032";
    lng = "13.3445";
}
logged to the console. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
float latFromTable = [[[displayItems objectForIndex:indexPath.row]
                                       [objectForKey:@"coords"]objectForKey:@"lat"] floatValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

A key-value pair within a dictionary is called an entry. Each entry consists of one OBJECT that represents the key and a second OBJECT that is that key’s value.

NSInteger is not an object (it is just an int value).

So, you cannot to do it

---ADDED
As schubam proposed, you can receive an NSString and call floatValue.

---ADDED2
I have read the log more accurately. You have an object with lat and long attributes. So, it is not a second-level dictionary. Try to receive the inteface name and get object of these interface.

Comment: No, you'd receive an NSNumber and call floatValue.

Comment: I have read the log more accurately. You have an object with lat and long attributes. So, it is not a second-level dictionary. Try to receive the inteface name and get object of these interface. I will add it to the answer

Comment: An "object" and a dictionary are the same thing.

Comment: Dictionary is a kind of object, but Object is not a kind of Dictionary. So, Object != Dictionary.

Comment: Also, you can review [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html). There is no any objectForKey or etc. But, looks like you are correct with NSNumber. It has floatValue.

Comment: Ivan, what is an "object" in JSON parlance is a "dictionary" in Objective-C and most other languages.